# Make the logo smaller without being blurry

Tags: logo

How can i get a small version of my logo? Like a favicon. I tryed but it results blurry!

Which is the best way to get my logo really small? Do you have any tutorial for this?

Thanks

Comment: If you post your logo, you might get some better responses; I don't think the answer to this is a simple one that can be easily generalized. Also, what is the source file for your logo and what programs did you use to create it?

Comment: Depends on what your logo looks like. You may have to re-design it like KMSTR posted. Can you share it with us ?

Answer (score 4):

Resizing alone won't do it in most cases. You have to re-design it. Simplify it. Look e.g. at the Mailchimp logo and how their favicon looks like. Its just the head of the chimp and re-drawn for 16x16px. This is a perfect example on how to use the small space available. But there are many more options. Look at good favicons. They sometimes crop the logo or only use part of it. But in most cases it is done pretty much pixel by pixel. So if you want a good result, this will be the way to go.

Good luck.

(And feel free to post your logo or versions of your favicon that you are working on for review)

Comment: Other classic examples: Google simplify their logo to "g", Microsoft to "M", Amazon to "A".

Comment: +1, pixel by pixel was to way to go for me. I chose the first letter of a logo and re-drew it checking it looked decent in the preview panel. I think I edited it in photoshop, but there are other options ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192537/where-can-i-find-a-good-desktop-favicon-ico-editor )